# For loop - find existing matches and move on to next type of match

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Hi I could use some help creating the logic for a function I am building.

Background: I want to recommend 3 vehicles that match the current vehicle type.  Problem is, sometimes only 1 or 2 other vehicles types match the existing vehicle type.  In this case, I want to run a loop that grabs the two vehicles that match the current type and then grab the highest price vehicle that doesn't match.

How do I tell my for loop, when it's met all the matching vehicle types, move onto the next vehicle type and grab the most expensive?

```
var currentType = "SUV";
var myArray = [
0: {index: 8, type: "SUV", value: 932.2}
1: {index: 6, type: "Sedan", value: 749.12}
2: {index: 7, type: "Sedan", value: 641.3}
3: {index: 5, type: "SUV", value: 621.24}
4: {index: 9, type: "Sedan", value: 591.14}
5: {index: 10, type: "Sedan", value: 568.57}
6: {index: 2, type: "Sedan", value: 420.61}
7: {index: 4, type: "Sedan", value: 415.6}
8: {index: 3, type: "Sedan", value: 415.6}
9: {index: 1, type: "Sedan", value: 410.58}
10: {index: 0, type: "Sedan", value: 410.58}
]

for(i=0; i<myArray.length'i++){
  if(myArray[i].type === currentType){
    //grab those vehicles and do X
  }else{
    //grab the most expensive vehicle of some other type
  }


}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way - filter the list for matching types, then (if needed) reverse-filter, sort and slice what you need from the rest.

```js
const myArray = [
{index: 8, type: "SUV", value: 932.2},{index: 6, type: "Sedan", value: 749.12},{index: 7, type: "Sedan", value: 641.3},{index: 5, type: "SUV", value: 621.24},{index: 9, type: "Sedan", value: 591.14},{index: 10, type: "Sedan", value: 568.57},{index: 2, type: "Sedan", value: 420.61},{index: 4, type: "Sedan", value: 415.6},{index: 3, type: "Sedan", value: 415.6},{index: 1, type: "Sedan", value: 410.58},{index: 0, type: "Sedan", value: 410.58}].sort((a, b) => a.value > b.value);

const getMatch = type => {
  let matches = myArray.filter(e => e.type === type);
  if (matches.length < 3) matches = matches.concat(myArray.filter(e => e.type !== type).slice(0, 3 - matches.length))
  return matches
}

console.log(getMatch('SUV'))
```

Comment: this works, thank you.  I just need to tweak it for scenarios where there are more than 3 matching types to only output the top 3 most expensive.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: I updated the answer and stuck the `sort()` on the original array declaration. Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient way of doing it, but I believe it to be very readable. It also is not using a loop, but if that is a requirement, I believe the reader can translate successfully.

I also assume from the example that the `myArray` is sorted by cost by default.

```js
var onlyType = myArray.filter(x => x.type == currentType) //filter by type
if(onlyType.length > 3)
  onlyType.length = 3 //truncate
else if(onlyType.length < 3)
  onlyType = onlyType.concat(myArray.slice(0, 3 - onlyType.length)) //add the missing
```

Comment: This also works, however kinglish put his answer in first, so I gave an upvote.